# Developer token for google adwords test account

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I have a problem with my PHP Google Adwords script.

I create test account and now I can't find developer token.

All my method:

code #1 auth.ini

```
developerToken = "INSERT_DEVELOPER_TOKEN_HERE"
userAgent = "INSERT_COMPANY_NAME_HERE"

...

; clientCustomerId = "INSERT_CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID_HERE"

[OAUTH2]
...
client_id = "someval"
client_secret = "someval"
...
refresh_token = "someval"
```

And now when I use command :

> php GetCampaigns.php 
>   An error has occurred: Validation failed for [userAgent] with value []: The property userAgent is required and cannot be null, the empty string, or the default [INSERT_COMPANY_NAME_HERE]

I don't know developer token for test account

[image]

And that's why I'm using client id
code #2 auth.ini

```
developerToken = "someval"
userAgent = "Some COmpany"

...

; clientCustomerId = "INSERT_CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID_HERE"

[OAUTH2]
...
client_id = "someval"
client_secret = "someval"
...
refresh_token = "someval"
```

And now when I use command :

> php GetCampaigns.php  An error has occurred:
>   [AuthenticationError.CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID_IS_REQUIRED @ ;
>   trigger:'']

And three options when in

```
 developerToken = 1111-11-11 and clientCustomerId = 1111-11-11
```

> php GetCampaigns.php  An error has occurred:
>   [QuotaCheckError.INVALID_TOKEN_HEADER @ ; trigger:'1111-11-11 ']

Comment: I don't understand you :/ In console.developers.google.com I create credentials for OAuth Client Id -> other

Comment: Actually you will have to revoke access for that specific refresh token because someone might have already copied it.

Comment: For me it's not problem because this account is be deleted. I use this account for test only.

Comment: That might be true, but the refresh token will work for any future account that you will have access to. It's bound to your Google account.

Comment: Well already removed the data, we can go back to why it does not work? :)

Comment: What is the developer token in test account ?!?!?!

Answer (score 0):

There is no developer token available in test accounts. You need to create a production MCC account as described [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/signup).

[e] As the Sandbox API was being mentioned in the comments—this option has been [shut down](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.ch/2012/11/introducing-test-accounts.html) a **long** time ago.

The only way to test your Adwords API code before running it on production is to use a [test account](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/accounts-overview#test_accounts).

You will **still** need a developer token to access a test account, but it does not have to be **approved** yet.

So it still holds that you **have** to create a production MCC Adwords account, otherwise it will be impossible to get hold of a developer token.

Comment: ok, but I need write php code with adwords api and I would like to have test account. Is it some method to write code with APi from test account ?

Comment: When you request Adwords API access, you'll get a developer token that is pending approval, which you can use for test accounts. It's all described in the guide I linked above really.

Comment: Now I create new accout and get this error QuotaCheckError.DEVELOPER_TOKEN_NOT_APPROVED

Comment: My token have Access level  Test Accounts And whats next ? I can't use API ?

Comment: If your token has access level Test Accounts, then you can use the API to access test accounts. No surprises here.

Comment: definitely not an answer, @bradley546994 is asking on how to work without access tokens (sandbox account) just like old adwords https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Idvia4600_E

Comment: wow :) I never thought I would see again the comment under this post :) I do not even work for this company;)

Comment: @Mark, the Sandbox environment has been gone for something like 5 years.If you want to use a test account, you'll need a deveoper token from a production account. No way around that.